Minimize function of two variables
Let $x,y$ be the column vectors $(n,1)$, $A(n,n)$ be the matrix, and
$$\Phi(x,y)=\left\Vert x^{T}Ay-y^{T}Ax\right\Vert _{2}^{2},$$
be the minimized function of two variables $x,y$. The function can be rewritten as
$$\Phi =(x^{T}Ay-y^{T}Ax)^{T}(x^{T}Ay-y^{T}Ax)
 =y^{T}A^{T}xx^{T}Ay-2y^{T}A^{T}xy^{T}Ax+x^{T}A^{T}yy^{T}Ax.$$
Using the symmetry
\begin{align*}
y^{T}A^{T}xx^{T}Ay & =xAyy^{T}A^{T}x,\\
y^{T}A^{T}xy^{T}Ax & =x^{T}Ayx^{T}A^{T}y,\\
x^{T}A^{T}yy^{T}Ax & =y^{T}Axx^{T}A^{T}y,
\end{align*}
the extremes can be determined from conditions
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial\Phi(x,y)}{\partial x} & =2Ayy^{T}A^{T}x-2Ayx^{T}A^{T}y+2A^{T}yy^{T}Ax=0,\\
\frac{\partial\Phi(x,y)}{\partial y} & =2A^{T}xx^{T}Ay-2Ayx^{T}A^{T}y+2Axx^{T}A^{T}y=0.
\end{align*}
Is there any analytic (non trivial) solution of the problem? This might be an analogy of a previously solved problem...
Thanks for your help.
Update:
I have now noticed that for the given $A$ it is
$$
\Phi(x,y)=\left\Vert x^{T}Ay-y^{T}Ax\right\Vert _{2}^{2}=\left\Vert x^{T}Ay-x^{T}A^{T}y\right\Vert _{2}^{2}=\left\Vert x^{T}(A^{T}-A)y\right\Vert _{2}^{2}.
$$
The solution $\min(\Phi(x,y))$ might have a simpler form.

$x=y=0$ is a solution

As a consequence of @daw 's remark the problem reduces to finding the pairs $(x, y)$ such that $x^T A y - y^T A x = 0$

@ daw: Good comment, but I would like to obtain a non-trivial solution of the problem...

Take any vector $x$, then take any vector $y$ orthogonal to $(A-A^T)x$

@
Gribouillis
However, we throw away some solutions. Analogy: the least square problem
$\left\Vert Ax-b\right\Vert _{2}^{2}$ leads to $x=(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}b.$

@ Is it possible to find the exact solution in a closed form?

@justik Your formula for the problem $|Ax - b|^2$ is incorrect, because when $A$ is a square matrix,  if $A$ is not invertible, neither is $A^T A$, and if $A$ is invertible, the formula reduces to $x = A^{-1}b$ which is obviously the only solution. In any case, we don't throw away any solution with the comment I made above.

@ Gribouillis Thank you very much for your explanation.
